# Live search using ajax in symfony

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I wanted to implement a live search using ajax in symfony. I wanted to search from a list which is already displayed and wanted to filter and show the results in the same place. This is what i have done so far.

Controller:

```
    $searchTerm = $request->query->get('search');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $search = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Classified')->searchClassifieds($searchTerm);


    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return JsonResponse::create(['status' => 'success', 'results' => $search]);

    }

    return $this->render('classifiedList.html.twig', [
        'classifiedList' => $search
    ]);
```

Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#search").on('keyup', function(e) { // everytime keyup event
           $('#spinner').show();
           e.preventDefault();
           var input = $(this).val();// We take the input value
           var $search = $('#search');

           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "{{ path('search') }}",
               dataType: "json",
               data: $search.serialize(),
               cache: false,
               success: function(response) {
                   $('.card-deck').replaceWith(response);
                   $('#spinner').hide();
                   console.log(response);
               },
               error: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

Twig:

```
<div class="card-deck">
   <i id="spinner" style="display:none; font-size: 20px" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
   {% for classified in classifiedList %}
        <div class="card">

            <a href="{{ path('classified_show',{'classifiedId' : classified.id}) }}">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ asset(classified.image) }}" alt="{{ classified.title }}">
            </a>

            <div class="card-block">
                <a href="{{ path('classified_show',{'classifiedId' : classified.id}) }}" class="classified-title">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ classified.title }}</h5>
                </a>
                <p class="card-text classified-brand">{{ classified.brand.name }}</p>
                <p class="card-text classified-price">{{ classified.price }}€</p>
                <p class="card-text classified-status">{{ classified.statusId }}</p>
                <p class="card-text classified-type">{{ classified.typeId }}</p>
                <a href="{{ path('classified_show',{'classifiedId' : classified.id}) }}" class="btn btn-primary details-button">Details</a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer">
                <p class="card-text classified-user"><i>{% trans %}by{% endtrans %} {{ classified.user }}</i></p>
                <div class="classified-date"><i>{{ classified.createdAt|time_diff  }}</i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

It is working and I can see it is getting the result in console. But somehow it is not displaying the result.

Thanks.

Comment: What's returned?

Comment: @Veve When I type sometthing that is in the list, that object(a product in my case) matching the name is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I done and its working.

```
        $searchTerm = $request->query->get('search');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $search = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Classified')->searchClassifieds($searchTerm);

    $results = $query->getResult();

    $content = $this->renderView('search-result.html.twig', [
        'results' => $results
    ]);

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('classifiedList' => $content));
    return $response;
```

And a some changes in ajax as well

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "{{ path('search') }}",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {search: input},
         cache: false,
         success: function (response) {
                $('.card-deck').html(response.classifiedList);
                $('#spinner').hide();
                 console.log(response);
                  },
         error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                    }
       });
```

And also note that the resulting template should not extend any other template.

Answer (score 0):

The response is a js object, and you are trying to replace the html with that. You need to do some rendering in js or return the html to replace the previous html.

Comment: Any idea how to render?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid expected format json and return a html

**dataType** is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.

```
   $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "{{ path('search') }}",
           data: $search.serialize(),
           cache: false,
           success: function(response) {
               $('.card-deck').replaceWith(response);
               $('#spinner').hide();
               console.log(response);
           },
           error: function(response) {
               console.log(response);
           }
       });
```

or

```
     $('.card-deck').load("{{ path('search') }}?search="+ $search.val());
```

and update your controller:

```
$searchTerm = $request->query->get('search');

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$search = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Classified')->searchClassifieds($searchTerm);

return $this->render('classifiedList.html.twig', [
 'classifiedList' => $search
]);
```

Comment: ups sorry, remove the part for ajax in your controller, the complete if condition